# Expected Initilizer Before Struct C++

Tags: c++, struct

I'm getting an error stating **"expected initilizer before struct"** in the first line.I'm confused about whats wrong in the program.

I am learing this from udemy and im kinda average with c++,If anybody knows whats wrong please let me know.**THANK YOU**.

```
#ifndef HELPER_H
#define HELPER_H

#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

namespace Helper
{
    template <class T>

    std::string ToString(const T &);

    struct DateTime
     {
         DateTime()
         {
             time_t ms;
             time (&ms);

             struct tm *info = localtime(&ms);

             D = info->tm_mday;
             m = info->tm_mon + 1;
             y = 1900 + info->tm_year;
             M = info->tm_min;
             H = info->tm_hour;
             S = info->tm_sec;
         }


         DateTime(int D,int m,int y,int M,int H,int S):D(D),m(m),y(y),H(H),M(M),S(S) {}
         DateTime(int D,int m,int y) : D(D) , y(y) , m(m) , H(0) , M(0) , S(0) {}

         DateTime Now() const
         {
             return DateTime();
         }

         int D,m,y,H,M,S;

         std::string GetDateString() const
         {
             return std::string(D < 10 ? "0" : "") + ToString(D) +
                    std::string(m <10 ? ".0" : ".") + ToString(m) + "." +
                    ToString(y);
         }

         std::string GetTimeString(const std::string &sep = ":") const
         {
             return std::string(H< 10 ? "0" : "") + ToString(H) + sep +
                    std::string(M< 10 ? "0" : "") + ToString(M) + sep +
                    std::string(S<10 ? sep : "") + ToString(S);
         }

         std::string GetDateTimeString(const std::string &sep = ":") const
         {
             return GetDateString() + " " + GetTimeString(sep);

         }

     };
     template<class T>

     std::string ToString(const T &e)
     {
         std::ostringstream s;
         s << e;
         return s.str();
     }

     void WriteAppLog(const std::string &s)
     {
         std::ofstream file("AppLog.txt", std::ios::app);
         file << "[" << Helper::DateTime.GetDateTimeString() << "[" << "\n" << s << std::endl << "\n";
         file.close();

     }
}

#endif // HELPER_H
```

**EDIT** 
This is the error i'm gettin.

> > F:\Work related\Helper.h:41:18: warning: 'Helper::DateTime::y' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
>
> F:\Work related\Keylogger\Helper.h:41:16: warning: 'intHelper::DateTime::m' [-Wreorder]
>
> ```
>             ^
> ```
>
> F:\Work related\Keylogger\Helper.h:34:10: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
>
> DateTime(int D,int m,int y) : D(D) , y(y) , m(m) , H(0) , M(0) , S(0) {}

Comment: You are missing a ; after the function decalaration.

Comment: Nevermind. There is a missing semicolon BEFORE the struct

Comment: i have closed the struct function with a semicolen but still having the same error,couldnt upload the end because i had more code than word :(

Comment: can you post your code properly there are lot of typo and scope issue

Comment: You haven't made the suggested change. Start with following the suggestion.

Comment: @user4581301 have removed the link and added the complete code.

Comment: The second message is a warning from the compiler . Member Variables are initialized in the order they have been defined, not the order they are listed in the member initializer list. This means that `int D,m,y,H,M,S;` will initialize `D`, then `m`, then `y` and not as specified here: `DateTime(int D,int m,int y) : D(D) , y(y) , m(m)` This doesn't matter much, but it is vitally important if the initialization of `m` depended on the value of `y`.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for making me understand better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon before the struct definition. It is:

```
std::string ToString(const T &)

struct DateTime
```

It should be:

```
std::string ToString(const T &);

struct DateTime
```

Comment: i did the change now i'm having 3 different warning

Comment: Could you post the error messages? They are because of something else, though

Comment: Well those are just warnings about the constructor initializing the values in a different order than they are declared. Seems like you can ignore them. Have a google search or open another question

Comment: Thanks a lot dude,will search it up.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, saw your edit with the code just now.

I guess the problem is that you don't declare the object in the function `WriteAppLog`. Try to change it to:

```
 void WriteAppLog(const std::string &s)
     {
         Helper::DateTime dateTime;
         std::ofstream file("AppLog.txt", std::ios::app);
         file << "[" << dateTime.GetDateTimeString() << "[" << "\n" << s << std::endl << "\n";
         file.close();
     }
```